# How to normalize a multidimensional histogram

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to calculate the normalized colour histigram (in HSV colourspace) of an image. Using  [histcn](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23897-n-dimensional-histogram/content/histcn.m) in Matlab  with 8 bins for Hue and 4 bins for each of Saturation and Value I get a 8x4x4 histogram. How could I normalize it?

Comment: What dou you mean when you say you have a 8x4x4 histogram. Do you have a 8x4x4  cell or matrix or something else ?

Comment: It's a 8x4x4 matrix, each element of which contains the number of pixels that their HSV values belong to the specific bin.

Comment: I am not familiar with histograms , so can you give an example for original matrix and normalized matrix

Comment: Actually, I don't have an example and I don't get what normalization means in that (4d) case. In simple histograms (1d) normalization is performed by dividing by the area. What is the equivalent in the 4d case?

Comment: I would say that it should be divided by the number of counts of your 3d histogram. so therefore HSV_hist./sum(HSV_hist(:))

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro So, dividing by the number of pixels?

Comment: if your 3d histogram was created based on the full 3d-image then it should be the number of entries of the 3d matrix. but as I said you can use the histogram for that

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand what you are saying. sum(HSV_hist(:)) equals the number of pixels of the image. what am I missing?

Comment: @Oliver: The `sum` command and `length` are equivalent as you have suspected.  I would use `numel` instead as this counts the total number of elements **across all dimensions**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @ASantosRibeiro is right, you just need to divide by number of elements like

```
HSV_hist ./ length(InitialData);
```

or

```
HSV_hist ./ sum(HSV_hist(:)); % To count the number of element use to create your hist.
```